# Redirecting Domain Only

Tags: wordpress, redirect, hosting, cpanel, host

This may be a very very basic question but i am totally new to this and there are tons of solutions on internet for pointing domain.

What i want to achieve is that domain needs to redirect to my hostgator server but i want emails to remain on godaddy server. Domain is on Godaddy right now, so if i change ARecord to point to my hostgator IP address will it effect emails?

Note i only want to point to hostgator for domain not for email. See attached screenshot and let me know that adding IP will do the job or not.

Thanks[Screenshot of Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIhtM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if your MX records point to mail.DOMAINX.com then if you leave your mail A record alone,  it will continue to point to where it points to now.

Most likely you have an MX record that points at mail.DOMAINX.com, and your A record tells the world that mail.DOMAINX.com is found at 66.193.60.9.    So you have to be careful not to mess with either of those if you want it to continue pointing where you need.

You can learn more about MX records and A records from [copernica here](http://www.copernica.com/en/blog/a-record-and-mx-record-how-does-it-work)

You can use this [Bulk DNS tool](http://www.matraex.com/quick-domain-research.php) tool I wrote to show you all the important DNS records that the outside world sees on your computer

Comment: Ok thanks for answering... final question where should i put 2nd server ip where i want to point domain....

Comment: Plus i don't want emails to get effected or moved... just want website to point on different host.

Comment: replace the ip that you crossed out in the screen shot